# Simple If and or statement

Tags: if-statement, sas

Hello i am trying to write what i thought would be a simple if and or statement in sas but i am running into trouble. The first condition after the and statement -in this case- "Nbr = 1000" does not process and is skipped over.

```
data want;
set have;
if family = "Pink flag" and NBR = 1000 OR NBR = 1500 
   then place = PF;
if family = "Blue Flag" and NBR = 2500 OR NBR = 2000
   then place = BF;
 /* this logic is repeated with different family names, nbrs and places */
run;
```

this is the output i get

```
family    NBR       Place
Pink Flag 1000      NJ
Pink Flag 1000      NJ
Pink Flag 1000      NJ
Pink Flag 1025      NJ
Pink Flag 1025      NJ
Pink Flag 1025      NJ
Pink Flag 1500      PF
Pink Flag 1500      PF
Pink Flag 1500      PF
Blue Flag 1000      BF
Blue Flag 2000      BF
Blue Flag 2000      BF
Blue Flag 2025      NJ
Blue Flag 2025      NJ
Blue Flag 2025      NJ
Blue Flag 2500      BF
Blue Flag 2500      BF
Blue Flag 2500      BF
```

as you can see it works for the 1500 but not the 1000. It also works for the Blue flag too

what i want

```
family    NBR       Place
Pink Flag 1000      PF
Pink Flag 1000      PF
Pink Flag 1000      PF
Pink Flag 1025      NJ
Pink Flag 1025      NJ
Pink Flag 1025      NJ
Pink Flag 1500      PF
Pink Flag 1500      PF
Pink Flag 1500      PF
Blue Flag 1000      BF
Blue Flag 2000      BF
Blue Flag 2000      BF
Blue Flag 2025      NJ
Blue Flag 2025      NJ
Blue Flag 2025      NJ
Blue Flag 2500      BF
Blue Flag 2500      BF
Blue Flag 2500      BF
```

i have also tried to use a where statement.

Thanks!

Comment: So do you only want to change values where family has a value of Pink Flag?  If so then make that clear in your logic.  `(family = "Pink flag") and (....)`

Comment: i want to change values where it has a value of BOTH pink flag and one of the following numbers: 1000, 1500. It works for the following flags but for some reason it is not registering the 1000. Also yes i notice the BF is not in ascending order for flag it is just the way the people sent me the data and i inputted it (it is sorted on another variable named ID which is not mentioned here)

Comment: Is NBR numeric or character?  Did you try rounding the value before comparing to 1000?

Comment: Is PF the name of another variable? or did mean the literal character string  P and F?  `place='PF'`

Comment: Yes in my code i have place='PF' sorry for leaving that out i will update it. I also just got it to work. i tried Reeza's "and (NBR = 1000..." solution again after closing and opening sas and it worked. I do not know how that could happen, i am just assuming the file would not update correctly even though i received no error messages. Any idea on what couldve been happening?

Comment: You might have had unbalanced quotes (or perhaps parens) so SAS was just taking the code and waiting for the end of the definition of the data step.

Comment: That would make sense. As always, thanks for your help Tom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IN instead of the OR's which are incorrectly specified:

```
if family = "Pink flag" and NBR in ( 1000, 1500, 2500) 
         then place = PF;
```

Your OR conditions aren't being evaluated the way you thing and you should have brackets around those conditions. You're also missing the last equal sign.

This would also work:

```
if family = "Pink flag" and (NBR = 1000 OR NBR = 1500 OR NBR = 2500) then place = PF;
```

I'm assuming you've misttyped the 1025 in your example code versus the 1500 in the code. I'll let you fix that as needed because they don't currently align.

Comment: Reeza, you are correct i mistyped some of the code above. I have since corrected it. I also have tried both methods mentioned above. Both methods results in NJ for all NBR's

Comment: Reeza, i closed and opened SAS and tried your bottom suggestion and it worked perfectly this time. Thanks for your help. I do not know what went wrong but a simple reboot seemed to do the trick